# How do I show the Prices on January 1 of 2017, 18, 19, 20, 21, and 22 in my dataframe? Python

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

[image: Code]

I can't figure out how to get the first days of every year so that I can show the change.

Comment: Please do not use images of code. Read the help on how to ask.

Comment: That was my thought. Seemed logical. But it's not working because date is not a column, technically in my dataframe. If you call data.info() Date is not one of the columns. Open, Low, High, Close, Adj. Close, and Volume are. – 
Christopher Smith

Comment: I woudln't use images of code. But it had a glitch and wouldn't allow me to add my code. Kept saying that my code had spacing errors, even though it didn't. And I even tried to correct it multiple times but there was nothing wrong with the code. So, I posted a picture.

Comment: Well, understand that we do not want to type everything... I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Maybe try again

Answer (score 0):

Filter the dataframe using the date you want (simple example if the column is named `date` and you can compare with a string):

```
data[data['date'] == '2017-01-01']
```

Comment: That was my thought. Seemed logical. But it's not working because date is not a column, technically in my dataframe. If you call data.info() Date is not one of the columns. Open, Low, High, Close, Adj. Close, and Volume are.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your column that holds the dates is unnamed.
That column is called `index` by default even though you don't see that. So in order to iterate that column you will have to do something like this:

```py
date = data.index
```

To get first date of every year:

```py
first_dates = data.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(data.index).to_period('Y')).nth([0])
```